# Elasticsearch: Exists Query on Binary Field

Tags: elasticsearch

I am looking for a way to look up the number of documents that has a certain binary field "not set" in a mapped index. However, standard "Exists" query does not seem to work. Example:

```html
{
  "some-index": {
    "mappings": {
      "some-type": {
        "properties": {
          "data": {
            "type": "binary"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Query: 
`POST http://.../some-index/some-type/_search?size=1`

```html
{
  "query":{
    "exists":{
      "field":"data"
    }
  }
}
```

The query above would return 0 result no matter what. My guess is this is because Elasticsearch does not store binary fields in source by default, and "Exists" query only looks up the source.

Is there an alternative to using Exists query, ideally without using extra boolean field in mapping?

Answer (score 1):

Does the following do what you want... I'm creating a template with field1 set as binary type, then indexed a document with just field2 (which I didn't bother defining) then I'm searching for docs without field1. You can run these in the Dev Console in Kibana

```
PUT _template\binary 
{
          "template": "binary",
          "mappings": {
            "binary": {
              "properties": {

                  "field1": {
                    "type": "binary"
                  }
            }
          }
        }}

PUT /binary/type/1 
{
   "field2":"abc"
}

GET binary/_search
{
    "query": {
        "bool": {
            "must_not": {
                "exists": {
                    "field": "field1"
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

That should return the doc you just indexed... if you change it to the following, it shouldn't return anything because field2 is present!

```
GET binary/_search
{
    "query": {
        "bool": {
            "must_not": {
                "exists": {
                    "field": "field2"
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for helping out. Does it work correctly for documents which actually have `field1`, i.e. when you query {bool:{must:{exists:{field:"field1"}}}}? Last time when I tried, it didn't work. Or, as in your example, if you put a document which has both `field1` and `field2`? I suspect ES simply ignores the binary field on "Exists" query.

Comment: You're right, if you explicitly attempt to search a binary field Elastic states it's not searchable but you wanted to return docs that don't have the binary field set, which is possible using  `GET binary/type/_count
{
    "query": {
      "bool": {
        "must_not": {
          "exists" : { "field" : "field1" } 
        }
        
      }
    }
}` getting the number of docs in an index is simple enough, so can you subtract one from the other?

Comment: This query (and _search) returns all documents, regardless if the binary field is set or not :(

Comment: That blows... Looks like another field is in order - what are you ingesting with?

Comment: Customised data. I am flexible with adding one more field. It's just less maintainable.